# PyGame - Plotting a Pixel and Printing out it's coordinates

Tags: python, graphics, pygame, python-idle

This may seem like a really easy question to answer, but I'm just a beginner in need of quick help.

I'm trying to create a program that when you click somewhere on the pyGame window, it'll print out that you hit it with the left button on the mouse, and also print out co-ordinates of where it was pressed. I've got this already. I'm having problems with making it plot the pixel on the pyGame window. Basically, I want it to draw a pixel where I pressed down on the pyGame window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#import the module for use 
import pygame

#setting up some variables
running = 1
LEFT = 1 
#Set up the graphics area/screen
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,400))

#continuous loop to keep the graphics running
while running==1:
    event=pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        running=0
        pygame.quit()
    elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button==LEFT:
        print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d,%d)" %event.pos
    elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button==LEFT:
        print "You released the left mouse button at (%d,%d)" %event.pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the color of each pixel when you receive the mouse down event.

```
elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button==LEFT:
  print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d,%d)" %event.pos
  screen.set_at((event.pos.x, event.pos.y), pygame.Color(255,0,0,255))
```

Note that this will temporarily lock and unlock the Surface as needed.

Comment: If you could help, what exactly do I do with that?

Comment: @user1861480 - Made a change, it should change the color of every pixel you clicked and drag onto to red.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm a beginner at this. I wanted to know though, where in the code do I put this? Because I wanted it to be like when I click anywhere on a pyGame window, a new pixel will appear. When I put this code in, it tells me that x doesn't have an attribute

Answer (score 0):

I edited Aesthete's code to a working standalone example:

Depending what you are doing, get/setting individual pixels can be slow. ( There is Surfarray and Pixelarray if you need to. )

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Game(object):
    done = False
    def __init__(self, width=640, height=480):
        pygame.init()
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

        # start with empty screen, since we modify it every mouseclick
        self.screen.fill(Color("gray50"))

    def main_loop(self):
        while not self.done:
            # events
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: self.done = True
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE: self.done = True
                elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                    pass
                elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                    print "Click: ({})".format(event.pos)
                    self.screen.set_at(event.pos, Color("white"))

            # draw
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Game()
    g.main_loop()
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Gave me some error. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I didn't even use 'x'. It runs fine on mine.

Comment: Sorry, this was the error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/1234.py", line 34, in <module>
    g.main_loop()
  File "C:/Python26/1234.py", line 25, in main_loop
    print "Click: ({})".format(event.pos)
ValueError: zero length field name in format